# Valgrind give different memory leak for the same app

Tags: c++, valgrind

I have a project using I compile both with cmake and Makefile.
Both build system create same executable.
When I run valgrind on both of them I get different definitively lost bytes value.

main.cc

```
#include <GameWindow.h>
#include <Video.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/gl.h>
using namespace ugen;

char read()
{
    std::cin.ignore(std::cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());
    return std::cin.get();
}

int main()
{
    Video video;
    GameWindow win("Window", 0, 0, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN|SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    std::cin.sync_with_stdio(false);

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    win.updateDraw();
    read();

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    win.updateDraw();
    read();
    return 0;
}
```

The class Video  initiate SDL2.
The class GameWindow create SDL_Window context.
The Makefile version leak 20 bytes from SDL_TLS.
The CMake version leak 80 bytes even though it is from the same code and is a exact copy of the Makefile binaries.
I used valgrind to find memory leaks.

Comment: Fix the leaks in the bigger one then try it.

Comment: There is no bigger one, both executable are the same.
The linux 'diff' utility tell me that they are. Valgrind still give me different memory leak value.
20 bytes on Makefile binary.
80 bytes on CMake binary.
Both binary are similar in size contain.

Comment: Are they linking with exactly the same shared libraries? It's quite possible that rpath or something along those lines is configured slightly differently between the two different build systems. Anyways afaik SDL2 is known to leak ~ 100 bytes when you use it, and there's nothing you can do to fix it.

Comment: Yes, they are exactely the same. They should give because executable A = executable B. I know SDL2 leak, but I expect same equivalent executable to leak the same way.

Comment: Bigger meaning the "larger" leak.

Comment: There is two executable that come from the same code link the same way to same library. One is build with makefile, second is build with cmake.
Both are equivalent, mean no differents.
Valgrind shouldn't give different definitivaly lost value: they are not different.

Comment: Name of the executable change memory leak found by valgrind.

Answer (score 1):

The different value give by valgrind was linked to the name of the file, I suspect a memory leak from X11. This explain why the two executable had different memory leak value, they had different name.
Answered